# Same object property with different values

Tags: php

I have a problem occurring in one function, for me it's strange because I thought that the behaviour of objects were different. The function is:

```
function getMessages($imapCon)
{
    $messageHeaders = array();
    $tempObj = new stdClass();
    $totalMessages = imap_num_msg($imapCon);
    for ($i = $totalMessages; $i > 0; $i--) 
    {
        $headers = imap_headerinfo($imapCon, $i);
        $tempObj->Unseen = $headers->Unseen;
        $tempObj->fromaddress = $headers->fromaddress;
        $tempObj->Date = $headers->Date;
        $tempObj->Subject = $headers->Subject;
        $tempObj->uid = imap_uid($imapCon, $i);
        array_push($messageHeaders, $tempObj);
    }       
    return json_encode($messageHeaders);
}
```

In the json encoded, I get the same values for all properties (Unseen, fromaddress, Date...). The properties are set correct, but the values are duplicated. Why?
If I do something like:

```
    for ($i = $totalMessages; $i > 0; $i--) 
    {
        $tempObj = new stdClass();
        ...
        array_push($messageHeaders, $tempObj);
        unset($tempObj);
    }       
    return json_encode($messageHeaders);
}
```

declaring the object inside the for, it works. But I believe this is a poor fix and nor the right thing to do...

Comment: that is actually the right thing to do. the `$tempObj` in your `for-loop` is the same object in every cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a new $tempObj inside the loop is the right way. When you add this object into array, it's not copied, but a pointer to it is added into the array. Check this documentation - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#example-191 (look at the simple assignment, ignore the $reference variable for now).

So you end up with array containing the whole bunch of links pointing to the same object. But if you create a new $tempObj inside the loop, all objects will be different.

Alternatively, you can do this:

```
array_push($messageHeaders, clone($tempObj));
```

but although this will equally work in this case, it may not work if the $tempObj would have more complex structure, such as instances of othe classes as properties of $tempObj.

On a side note, in PHP4 your code would work as you expected as PHP4 was copying actual objects on assignment instead of just pointers as PHP5 does.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are just [pushing a reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) into the `$messageHeaders` array each time, but you are reassigning the data on the same instance. Not sure where you got the idea that it was wrong to create a new `$tempObj` on each iteration but that is one way you could solve this. Another way would be to just add to the `$messageHeaders` array directly like this:

```
$messageHeaders[] = array(
    'Unseen' => $headers->Unseen,
    'fromaddress' => $headers->fromaddress,
    'Date' => $headers->Date,
    'Subject' => $headers->Subject,
    'uid' => imap_uid($imapCon, $i)
);
```